# Why does CombineLatest modify observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, combinelatest

In my Angular app I have this simple stream for a search bar.

**.ts**

```
user$: Observable<User> = this.authService.user$;
ally$: Observable<UserAndMatch> = this.user$.pipe(
  switchMap((user: User) =>
    this.userService.getFollowing(user)
  shareReplay(1),
);
filteredAlly$: Observable<UserAndMatch> = new Observable<UserAndMatch>();
@ViewChild('search') search: ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  const query$ = fromEvent(this.search.nativeElement, 'input').pipe(
    debounceTime(200),
    map(() => this.search.nativeElement.value),
    startWith(''),
    map((query: string) => query.trim().toLowerCase()),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
  );

  this.filteredAlly$ = combineLatest([query$, this.ally$]).pipe(
    map(([query, ally]: [string, UserAndMatch]) => {
      return !query ? ally : this.allyFilter(ally, query)
    }),
  );
}

 allyFilter(ally, query) {
   ally.users = ally.users.filter(user => user.name.includes(query));
   return ally;
 }
```

**.html**

```
  <form autocomplete="off">       
       <input
         #search
       />
   </form>
   <ng-container *ngrxLet="filteredAlly$ as ally"></ng-container
```

The stream works as expected when typing a word, but when the user deletes some letters the array from `filteredAlly$` doesn't repopulate and, logging the values in the `ally$` pipeline, I found out that `ally$` values are being filtered too, while I wanted them to be a "backup" to apply some filter function to which should return `filteredAlly$`

Comment: Something's not right, because filteredAlly$ is a UserAndMatch, but your `map` is returning an array of users. I'd start by strongly typing `allyFilter` and going from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probable culprit is the first line of `allyFilter`:

```
ally.users = ally.users.filter(user => user.name.includes(query));
```

You're modifying `ally.users` in place, instead of creating a copy. This means that you're shortening the list of allies when the user is typing, and you're not getting a "fresh" copy of allies later, when the user deletes the characters.

It will probably suffice to shallow-copy ally object in allyFilter, like so:

```
 allyFilter(ally, query) {
   return {
     ...ally,
     users: ally.users.filter(user => user.name.includes(query));
   };
 }
```